# How to Display Animated GIF in ImageView

Tags: android, animated-gif

How to display Animated Gif in Imageview I had Used Gif from Drawable folder its not Displying like Gif. Nee Help plz

Here is m my Imageview Code

```
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/ivGif"
            android:src="@drawable/success_bg"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:gravity="center|bottom"
            android:visibility="visible" />
```

Comment: I don't understand, what do you want. See this answer  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33752578/how-to-display-gif-on-android-device?rq=1), or try this [library](https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable)

Comment: Its not understandable question, may you have to use http://stackoverflow.com/a/34870817/1318946

Comment: Try solution in given link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533942/adding-gif-image-in-an-imageview-in-android

Comment: if you have to set gif in imageview use GLIDE

Comment: i corrected my question

Comment: thanks for response friends

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display Animated GIF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660209/display-animated-gif)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding gif image in an ImageView in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533942/adding-gif-image-in-an-imageview-in-android)

Comment: Use this link https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable

Comment: how dumb question that was

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**i just used this code and its working** 
first add library

*compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.3'*

then set gif layout where you want to put gif like this

```
<pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/your_gif"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this library

**compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.3'**

```
<pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
        android:id="@+id/gif_iv"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_ani_gif"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/rl_holder_view"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="center|top" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
 "android.resource://[package]/[res id]"

    Uri myUri =("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/"
                        + R.drwable.mygifimage);
    try{
        Url myUrl = myUri.toURL();
        webView wView = new webView(this);   
        wView.loadUrl(myUrl);
        setContentView(view);

       }catch(Exception e){
              e.printStackTrace()
       }
```